# What is the Best way for LARAVEL database connection

Tags: laravel-5.4

I am using laravel 5.4, and I put all database details in .env file for connecting database, but unfortunately, this details can see my URL path, so what is the best solution for declare database details in Laravel,
thank you
[this is the screen short of accessing .env file through URL](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B2vTN.png)

Comment: you didn't declare your DataBase name, login and password. Firstly you have to create a DB, then you can use it by declaring DB name in `.env`. Also, usually you may use `root` login and empty password, since root has no password by default

Comment: thank you for your quick response, and in this project  i put "DataBase name, login and password" in database.php file, but they are saying that '.env' file is most secure than 'database.php', but when i put 'DataBase name, login and password' in .env file, i can read that also

Comment: It doesn't matter whether **you** can read it :) No one can access this file outside.

Comment: @Sergey Gultyaev : lol, i can read means, everybody can see that .env file through URL , like 'http://localhost/Laravel-project-nale/.env'

Comment: no. The only `public` folder is shared. Other files are hidden. Don't believe me? Try to access it as you said :)

Comment: @Sergey Gultyaev : i am not trying to make you temper, and i had put a link to a screenshot that i can read .env file in my question, :) , and i made that laravel project using composer, could your help me pls

Comment: I said. You cannot access it by link. I've just tried it. Nothing happens, because if it was accessible it would be insecure. Even my console after serving didn't show any tries to access this file. You can be confident, that if you use `.env` for connection to db, it won't be unsafe. It might be hacked if your server was hacked. The only files that are placed in `public` can be accessed.

Comment: If you couldn't read the `.env`, how would you configure it? :)

Comment: @Sergey : haha, i dont know, but its happening, i made the project using **composer**, and i did not make any changes , i just did on .env,

Comment: it's a bit strange

Comment: I'm sorry, but is it working? I mean did you invoke `php artisan serve`? It might listen to localhost:8000 by default

Comment: no , i did not, and i use *database.php** file for declare database connection, and its working

Comment: That's why it may be accessible. You might access it as FTP server. So, open the folder with project in console/cmd/powershell, then use `php artisan serve` and go to the offered link in the browser, then try to access your file again. I'm sure it won't be able to access it. `php artisan serve` starts your project as server and it becomes possible to work with it as with server, not ftp.

Comment: @SergeyGultyaev : ok

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can control it access by htaccess.

```
<Files .env>
order allow,deny
Deny from all
</Files>
```

This will prevent the access of .env file from url. Place this into your root htaccess file.
Thank you.

Comment: woww, thank you sir, its working, it was a big problem, but i  made the laravel project using composer, so we have to edit the .htaccess file alwas, right.?